# Some Activities are not seen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I want to create an empty activity but it doesn't show up. I googled and couldn't find anyone mentioned this issue I've been searching for 2 days [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzpis.png)

how can i solve this

sdafsafdas sadasdasd gsdfassdsdsdsdsdaa asdfafasfasf
fsasas

Comment: Have you looked into the Logcat? Maybe the app is crashing which makes it seem like it doesn't show up?

Comment: where can i look ?

Comment: In the Logcat, as I said.

Answer (score 0):

You added dummy text instead of explaining your problem. It's not a valid way to ask on StackOverflow.

See your answer in the below image.
[image]

More templates of Activity have gone in new updates. So you have to create you own way to make changes in your app